# Strategies to be more effective at programming in dynamic languages

Tags: javascript, python, language-agnostic, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I have a strong background in Java, which obviously is statically-typed, and type-safe language.

I find it that I am able to read through large amounts of code very quickly and easily assuming that the programmer who had written it followed basic conventions and best practices. I am also able to write code pretty quickly, given a pretty good IDE like Eclipse and IntelliJ because of the benefits of compilation and auto completion.

I'd like to become more proficient, effective and efficient at reading/writing code in more dynamic languages like Python and JavaScript. The problem is that I can't find myself understanding code nearly as fast as I would in Java mainly because I comprehend code very quickly based on their types. Also when writing, there really is no auto complete available to quickly see what methods are available. Edit -- I ask this in the context of larger-scale projects where the code continues to grow and evolve.

What are general strategies or caveats when reading and writing in languages like these when the project sizes are much larger and are non-trivial? Or does it come with time? Much thanks!

Comment: The only real way is to do it.  Pick a project, code it up.  Put it away for a month, come back, stare in horror at the code some noob wrote, refactor, refactor more, give up and rewrite the thing from scratch.  Put it away for a month...

Comment: What roippi describes is pretty much it. You know you've gotten out of the novice phase of your upbringing when you lose the urge to start from scratch every so often, and don't really need to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a C++/C# dev by training, and I found that I got better with JS after I started writing it. Try going all in on JS and write something in it. Maybe Node.js. Maybe learn to use it with a frontend framework like Angular or Knockout. Maybe both together.

If you want to improve from there, check out Douglas Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts". He writes some good suggestions on how to write better JS. It's not ironclad, community-proven best practices, but he offers some solid stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I've read a lot of books on JS and have even written in it for a smaller project of mine. I ask this when it comes to applying such techniques for much larger projects

Comment: I think that part of the challenge with JS is not just the language, but the frameworks. I'm really strong in a handful of frameworks, and I can read JS that uses them relatively quickly. If you hand me JS that relies heavily on a framework that I don't know anything about, that's going to slow me down a ton.